# Handling memory leaks caused by an external assembly

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, memory-leaks, dispose

I need to use an external assembly that I cannot modify. Suppose that I use a class from that assembly like so:

```
using (ExternalWidget widget = new ExternalWidget())
{
    widget.DoSomething();
}
```

Each time I call this code, it leaks unmanaged memory. `ExternalWidget` implements `IDisposable` and I have wrapped it in a `using` statement, but `ExternalWidget` does not clean up its unmanaged resources.

Since I do not have access to the `ExternalWidget` code, I cannot fix this issue the right way. Is there any other way that I can free up the memory resources used by `ExternalWidget`?

Comment: Create a small sample program that demonstrates the problem and contact the author of the library.

Comment: If you know the cause of the memory leak, you probably can use reflection to fix it (we had to do this with an old version of the Infragistics control library).

Comment: How do you know that it's not cleaning up unmanaged resources?

Comment: You can also disassemble the external assembly, fix the leak, then re-assemble it.

Comment: @Dan Puzey I used ANTS Memory Profiler and it shows that all of my .NET heaps are being freed each time I call the code. However, the unmanaged memory and total private bytes continue to rise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a true *unmanaged* memory leak and you can't change the code, then there's little that you can do.  The framework can't pick up on that, nor can it clean up that code.

The approach in this case would be isolation of that component.  It means there's going to be a lot of overhead in accessing it, but there's nothing else you can do.

You can't run the code in another application domain, because the unmanaged code has no concept of the application domain.

That leaves the process level.  I'd recommend creating a service contract in WCF that mimics the calls to the `ExternalWidget` along with a `Shutdown` method.

Then, you would create an EXE which would expose this contract (with a session, so you can hold onto the `ExternalWidget` instance, unless each call is stateless) through named pipe bindings.

As a parameter to the EXE, it would take a unique identifier (use a `Guid`) and use that as part of setting up the endpoint for the WCF service.

Then, you would make the calls, and when you're done with that instance of `ExternalWidget`, call `Shutdown`; the EXE would know to stop waiting and then the process will exit, and the operating system will reclaim the memory.

Of course, there's a *huge* amount of overhead here, so if you find you're making a lot of calls and don't need a new process for each set of calls, you can expand the idea into a service which counts the calls and then recycles the process (the service will still have to shell out, or *it* will run out of resources) when needed.

Note that if this turns out to be a *managed* memory issue, then you can always spin up a new application domain, run your code there (marshaling the results back and forth as needed) and then release the application domain.